# How to create multiple RichTextBoxes

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I need to crate a certain number of RichTextBoxes depending on User Input.
I can create one in visual studio using the toolbox, but how would I go about creating multiple through code?

UPDATE:

This is now my code:

```
RichTextBox richTextBox = new RichTextBox();
            richTextBox.Location = new Point(12, 169);

            richTextBox.Width = 62;
            richTextBox.Height = 76;
            this.Controls.Add(richTextBox);
```

Nothing happens when I run this

Comment: this.Controls.Add( new RichTextBox{...} )

Comment: @CetinBasoz I've tried that. Please see my updated question

Comment: @CetinBasoz It's been added now

Comment: What do mean by "nothing happens"? It is added and shown immediately, what else?

Comment: @CetinBasoz well its not showing on my screen at all

Comment: What is `this` in that context? Another `Control`? Are you calling `SuspendLayout()` previous to this?

Comment: @PietroNadalini how do I do that?

Comment: @Jimenemex this is from inside the Form class

Comment: Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610742/richtextbox-formatbar-in-code-behind) it might help you

Comment: Copy&paste the code I sent and try. (Hint: You can easily run it with LinqPad)

Comment: @Jimenemex, the form itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Here is a sample that shows that it works:

```
void Main()
{
    Form f = new Form();
    Button b = new Button();
    b.Click += (sender, args) =>
    {
        RichTextBox richTextBox = new RichTextBox
        {
            Name = "rtbBlahBlah",
            Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 169),
            Width = 62,
            Height = 76
        };
        f.Controls.Add(richTextBox);
    };

    f.Controls.Add(b);
    f.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `this.Refresh()` to refresh the `Control` and re-draw all the children within it.

From the [Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Forces the control to invalidate its client area and immediately redraw itself and any child controls.

Comment: this is not needed.